# While loop stuck at random points on the code

Tags: c#, loops, multidimensional-array, random

i need help, i had my friend to help me debug this code, and we found that the code stops at random points on the code, sometimes on first loop, sometimes on last loop and so on.
the code is just to make a 9x9 sudoku board with all the rules applied. when i tested each block separately it worked and printed a well done sudoku board, but the problem here is that is gets stuck somehow.
help will be appreciated.

```
int[,] helpblock = new int[10, 10];
int[,] helplines = new int[10, 10];
int[,] helpcols = new int[10, 10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        helplines[i, j] = 0;
        helpcols[i, j] = 0;
        helpblock[i, j] = 0;
    }
}

Random rnf = new Random();
int help1;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
        if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 2) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[0, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[0, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }
                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[0, help1]++;
            } else if (j == 3 || j == 4 || j == 5) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[1, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[1, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }
                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[1, help1]++;
            } else if (j == 6 || j == 7 || j == 8) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[2, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[2, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }
                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[2, help1]++;
            }
        } else if (i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 2) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[3, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[3, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }
                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[3, help1]++;
            } else if (j == 3 || j == 4 || j == 5) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[4, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[4, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }

                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[4, help1]++;
            } else if (j == 6 || j == 7 || j == 8) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[5, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[5, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }

                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[5, help1]++;

            }
        } else if (i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 2) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[6, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[6, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }

                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[6, help1]++;
            } else if (j == 3 || j == 4 || j == 5) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[7, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[7, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }

                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[7, help1]++;
            } else if (j == 6 || j == 7 || j == 8) {
                if (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[8, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                    while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[8, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
                    }
                }

                map[i, j] = help1;
                helplines[i, help1]++;
                helpcols[j, help1]++;
                helpblock[8, help1]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

PrintSudoku(map);
```

Comment: programmed in C#

Comment: Please specify the language you are using.

Comment: Do learn how to use a debugger. It will show exactly what is going on, especially when it's happening "sometimes." Also why allocate 10x10 array when using only 9x9?

Comment: Please read [How to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This looks like a situation that a [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) could help with

Comment: You have some redundant code in there that can be cleaned up - you can remove many of the `if` statements that are followed by a `while` statement that has the same condition, because if the condition is false, the flow will bypass the `while` anyway (A `while` block is basically an `if` block that loops).

Comment: Why do all your variables start by 'help' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but hopefully it will help you debug the program. Inside your `for` loops you have a whole bunch of `if` statements that look something like:

```
if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2) {
    if (j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 2) {
```

It looks like you are using this logic to determine which block you're in, because that's the one array that you are using a hard-coded value for the first index.

Instead of doing it this way, consider calculating the block using a formula based on the current row and column value.

Your grid currently looks something like this:

```
  | 0 1 2 | 3 4 5 | 6 7 8 |
--+-------+-------+--------
0 |       |       |       |
1 |  [0]  |  [1]  |  [2]  |
2 |       |       |       |
--+-------+-------+--------
3 |       |       |       |
4 |  [3]  |  [4]  |  [5]  |
5 |       |       |       |
--+-------+-------+--------
6 |       |       |       |
7 |  [6]  |  [7]  |  [8]  |
8 |       |       |       |
---------------------------
```

What you might notice is that if you take the row number and do an integer division by 3, you will get the `Block` row number (0, 1, or 2). Multiplying this number by 3 gives you the first block in each row (0, 3, and 6). Now, if we take the current column and integer-divide that by 3, we will get the current block column (0, 1, or 2). Adding the "block row" to the "block column" then will give us the block index:

```
int block = ((row / 3) * 3) + (column / 3);
```

(Note that it looks like you could simplify this since row is being divided by three and then multiplied by three, but remember that integer division rounds down, so `2 / 3 == 0`, not `.6667`)

By calculating the block this way, you can drastically reduce the number of lines you have to walk through.

Also, using some more meaningful variable names will help with the readability.

I simplified your code to something that I believe does the exact same thing. Maybe it will help your analysis:

```
int[,] blocks = new int[10, 10];
int[,] rows = new int[10, 10];
int[,] columns = new int[10, 10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        rows[i, j] = 0;
        columns[i, j] = 0;
        blocks[i, j] = 0;
    }
}

Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber;

for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
    {
        int block = ((row / 3) * 3) + (column / 3);
        randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 10);                    

        while (rows[row, randomNumber] != 0 || 
            blocks[block, randomNumber] != 0 || 
            columns[column, randomNumber] != 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        }

        map[row, column] = randomNumber;
        rows[row, randomNumber]++;
        columns[column, randomNumber]++;
        blocks[block, randomNumber]++;
    }
}
```

---

After playing with this, of course, I got interested in the problem. Below is what I came up with to solve it, which is pretty much a brute-force method:

1. Start with numbers 1-9 available for each row, column, and block
2. From the list of available numbers for a cell, assign one of them at random, one cell at a time
3. Remove that number from the available numbers for that row, column, and block
4. If we run into the case where there is no valid number available for the cell, reset everything and try again.

Notice there is potential that this will run and never finish, but in my testing it usually finds a solution in less than 400 tries (which is relatively fast from a user's point of view).

What I did differently was, instead of using arrays to store the row/column/block information, I decided to use a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`, which stores the row/column/block index as the key, and the value for each key is a `List` of available numbers for that index.

Then in our loop, I just put the intersection of the available numbers left for the current row, column, and block into a `List`. Then I pick a random index in that list and assign that value to the cell (and remove it from the available items in that row, column, and block).

I also added some logging to find out how many times it failed before finding a solution.

Here's the code, which also prints the solution at the end:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[,] map = new int[9, 9];
    var blocks = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    var rows = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    var columns = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    // initialize lists of available numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        blocks.Add(i, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
        rows.Add(i, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
        columns.Add(i, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int failCount = 0;

    // For each row
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        // For each column in this row
        for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
        {
            // Calculate block based on current row and column
            int block = ((row / 3) * 3) + (column / 3);

            // Get set of available numbers for this cell by getting the intersection
            // of available numbers for the row, column, and block
            var availableItems = 
                rows[row].Intersect(
                    columns[column].Intersect(
                        blocks[block])).ToList();

            // If we reach a point where there are no availableItems, then this is
            // not a valid Sudoku pattern. Reset everything and try again
            if (availableItems.Count == 0)
            {
                failCount++;
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed {failCount} times. Trying again...");

                // Reset to the first cell
                row = 0;
                column = 0;
                block = 0;

                // Initialize data
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    blocks[i] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
                    rows[i] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
                    columns[i] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
                }
                availableItems = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            }

            // Grab a number from the available numbers by choosing a random index
            var randomNumber = availableItems[rnd.Next(0, availableItems.Count)];

            // Update our map with this item
            map[row, column] = randomNumber;

            // Remove this item from our lists
            rows[row].Remove(randomNumber);
            columns[column].Remove(randomNumber);
            blocks[block].Remove(randomNumber);
        }
    }

    // Print our Sudoku map:
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25));

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("|");

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            Console.Write($" {map[i, j]}");
            if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0) Console.Write(" |");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25));
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These loops look deadly:

```
while (helplines[i, help1] != 0 || helpblock[5, help1] != 0 || helpcols[j, help1] != 0) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    help1 = rnf.Next(1, 10);
}
```

If the new value of `help1` doesn't change the `while` condition to `false`, it will loop forever.

Comment: i'll try looking into that a little bit further

Comment: Furthermore, this will also loop forever if none of the array items equal zero.

Comment: @RufusL it's worse than that. It will loop forever if *any* of the items are non zero (no matter how many are zero)